# POST data using XMLHttpRequest not working unless I put an alert prompt

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage in which you input a cost code, that is submitted and POST to a page `'process-cost-code.php'` which does basic validation checks and saves it to a database if all is right.  The process-cost-code.php page simply outputs a short message saying if it was successful or not.

I wanted to use JavaScript and `XMLHttpRequest`, to post this information without leaving the current page, and output the `responseText` to a `'feedback'` div.

I am a beginner at JavaScript and only use Notepad, so I tend to use alerts to display information. I managed to get it to work correctly, with the `responseText` displaying correctly in the feedback div.

I removed a couple of alerts I had and it stopped working completely.  The `responseText` is empty. Even if I put `"hello world"` into the body of `process-cost-code.php`, it returns nothing.

If I have the alert just after `.send`, it works again. If I comment the alert out, it doesn't work at all, no response. I have even tried adding a `wait` after the response and that made no difference.

Any ideas? Code below:

```js
    function submit_cost_code() {
      var costCode = document.getElementById("cost-code").value;
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var url = 'process-cost-code.php';
      var params = 'cost-code=' + costCode;
      xmlhttp.open('POST', url, true);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      xmlhttp.send(params);

      alert("Why does it only work when I have this aleart in?");

      document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
```

Comment: When you make an Ajax request using XMLHttpRequest, it will be asynchronous, so when it reaches the last line, it won't have finished yet, so `xmlhttp.responseText` won't have been populated yet. When you put the alert, it will stop the execution of the code until you close that alert, which is most likely more then enough time to finish and populate it. To solve it, follow _any_ guide/tutorial for XMLHttpRequest to see how to properly handle it. While you're at it, learn and use the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alert prompt just gives the script time to return with the response while you are clicking the OK button on that prompt. If the XMLHTTPRequest was slower and you where faster, you would get the same error.

You need to wait for the request to return and that is done using the load event. So, here I define the callback function before sending the request. In that way I'm sure to get things in the right order.

I replaced the URL with a data URI for the XMLHTTPRequest to make a functional example here in SO.

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  submit_cost_code(e.target.costcode.value);
});

function submit_cost_code(costCode) {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.addEventListener('load', e => {
    document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = e.target.responseText;
  });
  var url = 'data:text/plain,hello';
  var params = 'cost-code=' + costCode;
  xmlhttp.open('POST', url, true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xmlhttp.send(params);
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <input type="text" name="costcode" value="12">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="feedback"></div>
```

I don't know why you use the [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). Maybe for more control, but you can make something leaner with the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) (the content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is implyed when using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)):

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let data = new FormData(e.target);
  fetch('data:text/plain,hello', {method: 'POST', body: data})
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => {
      document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = text;
    });
});
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <input type="text" name="costcode" value="12">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="feedback"></div>
```

Comment: Try putting the important part of the answer on Stackoverflow instead of putting it on another site behind a URL

Comment: I dont really know Java or JS. I usually have enough knowledge to understand what its doing and then tweek and apply to fit my needs.
Your solution worked perfeclty, thanks.